# Extract elements from a named list while keeping the name in R

Tags: r, list, extract

I'm trying to extract a single element from a list in R and store the element with its vector name as a new list.

Let's assume that I have a list called mylist that has an arbitrary amount of named vectors within and the length of each vector can vary, e.g.

```
mylist <- list("var1" = c(1,2,3), "var2" = c(10,8,4,2), "var3" = c(6,3), ...)
```

I know I can get an individual element by using either the name or the index of the vector, e.g.

```
mylist[["var1"]][1]
[1] 1
mylist[[2]][3]
[1] 4
```

However, these are only the values. What I want is to create a new list from this extracted value and use the original name of the vector where it was extracted from, something like

```
element1
$var1
[1] 1

element2
$var2
[1] 4
```

where element1 and element2 are the new lists. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(mylist, c(1, 3), `[[`)
```

-output

```
#$var1
#[1] 1

#$var2
#[1] 4
```

---

or using `pluck`

```
map2(mylist, c(1, 3), pluck)
```

---

Or with `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(`[[`, mylist, c(1, 3))
```

-output

```
#$var1
#[1] 1

#$var2
#[1] 4
```

#### data

```
mylist <- list("var1" = c(1,2,3), "var2" = c(10,8,4,2))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was some simple way to do this. I will use Map so I don’t have to include dependencies in my package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `pluck` and `list` as shown below.

```
library(purrr)
mylist <- list("var1" = c(1,2,3), "var2" = c(10,8,4,2), "var3" = c(6,3))
element1 <- mylist %>% pluck("var1") %>% .[1] %>% list("var1" = .)
element2 <- mylist %>% pluck("var2") %>% .[3] %>% list("var2" = .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use `mapply()` defining a function with two elements: a list `x` and a vector `n` which contains the desired positions of elements to extract. With that you can wrap the function using indexing in order to obtain a list `L` close to what you expect. Here the code:

```
#Data
mylist <- list("var1" = c(1,2,3), "var2" = c(10,8,4,2))
#List
L <- mapply(function(x,n) x[n],x=mylist,n=c(1,3),SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Output:

```
L
$var1
[1] 1

$var2
[1] 4
```